# Can I delete a Platform Event from a Released 2GP Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, platform-event, 2gp, 2gp-ama

I am trying to confirm if I can delete a `Platform Event` after I've released it in a managed package.

There is documentation which should outline this:

- [Package and Distribute Your Apps: Components Available in Managed Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=packaging_packageable_components.htm&type=5)

But the terminology isn't clear.

There isn't an entry for `Platform Event`.

But there rows for:

- Lightning Event
- Platform Event Channel
- Platform Event Channel Member

Please could someone at Salesforce clarify if any of the above relate to the `Platform Event` object?

Specifically, I'd like to know if I can edit or delete `Platform Events` once the Managed Package has been released.

Comment: AFAIK you currently cannot remove/delete any components from a 2GP, which a platform event is. So I do not think you can delete it. You have the option of creating a separate version branch in your version structure, branching off from before the introduction of the platform event. Of course, you cannot then upgrade an existing install of the version that does include the platform event.

Comment: Phil's right - 2GP does not yet have managed component deletion, full stop

Comment: Thanks gents. And out of interest, which of the metadata items listed are `Platform Events` or are they not even listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing comments:

Second-generation packaging currently does not allow deletion of managed components of any type. It's on the list at [Gaps Between First-Generation and Second-Generation Managed Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_known_limitations.htm):

> Components can’t be deleted from packages.

While the page states

> We’re working to address these feature gaps.

I'm not aware of an accepted Idea or public road-map for that feature.

Platform Events are technically [`CustomObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_metadata_api.htm#!) in the Metadata API:

> Deploy and retrieve platform event definitions from your sandbox and production org as part of your app’s development life cycle.

> The CustomObject metadata type represents a platform event.